# Use of WidgetProperties.SingleSelectionIndex() of Combo box in SWT

Tags: java, combobox, swt

Can anyone explain the use of the `WidgetProperties.singleSelectionIndex().observe(combo)`?

I have read the API documentation for it. But I could not get a clear idea about it.

Answer (score 0):

This observes the value of the `Combo` `getSelectionIndex` value (and set with `select(index)`). This is the index of the currently item in the Combo items. You would only use this with a read only Combo.

Comment: This is my binding property `BeanProperties.value("USPComboIndex").observe(model);`.What will happen when the getUSPComboIndex() returns -1.?

Comment: The code for this is `org.eclipse.jface.internal.databinding.swt.ComboSingleSelectionIndexProperty`. A value of -1 causes that to call the `Combo` `deselectAll` method.